# How to install laravel app in subfolder of shared host?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, laravel, mod-rewrite

I install laravel app in root of my shared host "public_html now I want to install Russian version of this app in ru/ subfolder but when I go to example.com/ru I got 404 Page not found error. I use apache web server my .htaccess file in root folder contain these code

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On 
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

how should i change this configuration?

Thanks.

Comment: What's your directory structure? Whole laravel app in the `ru/` directory?

Comment: I have laravel app in root folder and another laravel app in subfolder /ru

Comment: this is image of directory structure in my host https://i.stack.imgur.com/BcC2B.png

Answer (score 4):

You will do it in the same way you installed it in the root directory. I will tell you how I installed it on my shared hosting account, both main and sub domains. After I uploaded all my project to the subfolder, and your will be `example.com/ru`, do the following:

1. In your public folder there is your `.htaccess` file. since you are basically making this a subdomain, it will need to be in the root of that subdomain, so transfer the `.htaccess` from public folder to the root of `ru` folder.
2. Open the `.htaccess` and change/add the following:

   ```
   DirectoryIndex public/index.php
   ```

   and in the `RewriteRule` change it to this:

   ```
   public/index.php
   ```

And just to be clear, your `.htaccess` should be like this at the end after your changes:

```
DirectoryIndex public/index.php
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ public/index.php [L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: i want a .htaccess configuration for if url start with /ru folder else go to public folder

Comment: For the main site you would need a separate `.htaccess`. because this is basically a "new website", or subdomain in your case. Try what i have written above, you will see it work fine.

Comment: I have a.htaccess in public_html and one .htaccess in /public also i have a .htaccess in /ru and one .htaccess in /ru/public which one should be remove? and wich one should be changed?

Comment: As i said, read what i have said again. you don't need 4 or 5 ht access files. only one for each site/subsite. The one in your public_html for the main site, you should keep. and you need one in your public_html for the `ru` folder. and that's it.

Comment: I did your advice but it doesn't still work thanks a lot

Comment: This seems to mostly work bar the assets in public. On my version the `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` is failing for my CSS because it's not including the public in the path. E.g I get `/var/www/mysite/mysubsite/css/app.css` instead of `/var/www/mysite/mysubsite/css/public/app.css`. Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: what if after do this my site returns a "404 NOT FOUND"??

Answer (score 3):

> Create a .htaccess file in a root folder and paste the code and save it.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
  Options -MultiViews
 </IfModule>

 RewriteEngine On

 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
 RewriteRule ^ ^$1 [N]

 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (\.\w+$) [NC]
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 

 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteRule ^ server.php
```