# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Route' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\code\project\routes\web.php:18

Tags: php, laravel, routes, xampp

I have a basic Laravel project, didn't do anything to it, I just did `laravel new project`. I started Xampp and turned on MYSQL and APACHE, and when I try to access `localhost/{path}/project` I get this:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Route' not found in
 C:\xampp\htdocs\code\project\routes\web.php:18 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in
 C:\xampp\htdocs\code\project\routes\web.php on line 18
```

I don't know if this is dumb, but I looked into web.php, and i don't even have 18 lines... it only has 16... Why is this happening, what should I do?

Comment: Have you run `composer install` and `composer dumpautoload`?

Comment: I didn't know i had to do this again... i installed caomposer and i thought that it is installd for all my projects. And about dumpautoload, what is that? I didn't used this one before?

Comment: Composer would be installed on the system, but what `composer install` does is install all of the libraries required for the project, listed in `composer.json`. `composer dumpautoload` removes the autogenerated composer.lock and regenerates it, which helps the project find all of the required libraries.

Comment: Thanks, I used both of those commands, but I get the same error...

Comment: what is your directory structure? show me your vendor directory

Comment: @DariusBiro Could you please show the code from your web.php

Comment: @KirenSiva  Here is how my folders look. I hope this is what you asked for: https://imgur.com/a/b1TXTNE

Comment: @ParantapParashar this is all I have in web.php: 
`Route::get('/', function () {     return view('welcome');    });`  
rest of the lines are just comments

Comment: try this: go to project folder and run `composer dumpautoload`. Try to cleae the route cache and shift+f5 for browser refresh

Comment: @KirenSiva did it and nope... still the same problem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did manage to figure this out. The problem was that i was trying to open the wrong file... I didn't really understand what everything does, but I'm getting there. Anyway, if there is anyone that has the same problem as me, [HERE](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7YezCyBbqI0) is the YouTube video that helped me. Hope it is useful for someone!

Answer (score 0):

Laravel expects that it is sitting at the root directory of your nginx/apache configuration.  If it sits in a subfolder, you need to configure a rewrite to handle the route accordingly.  See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41407758/how-to-install-laravel-app-in-subfolder-of-shared-host) link or [this](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/servers/how-to-install-laravel-app-in-subfolder-of-shared-host) link for details on how to appropriately set this up.

Comment: Ok, so that means that i have to put it in `xampp` folder,or in my `project` folder?

Comment: Hey @DariusBiro, sorry I didn't see your response.  Glad you were able to figure it out!